# How should I tag Splinter Cell Chaos Theory?

Tags: discussion, tags

`splinter-cell-chaos-theory` exceeds the maximum tag length, what should I call the tag instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that we have a tag limit of 35 characters, I have retagged all questions that had [splinter-cell-ct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splinter-cell-ct) with [splinter-cell-chaos-theory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splinter-cell-chaos-theory).